# Ergodic Theorems Birkhoff and Von Neumann

Tags: ergodic-theory

Is that possible to derive the Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem from or with the help of the Von Neumann ergodic theorem?

Comment: since Von Neumann only addresses average properties and Birkhoff applies to each individual trajectory, to derive the latter from the former is unlikely.

Comment: It depends on what you call you call derive one theorem from another. Using the maximal inequality lemma, you can prove that the Birkhoff sums of a function $f$ almost surely converge. Von Neumann ergodic theorem then tells you that this limit is actually the integral of $f$. But you need $f$ to be $L^2$, otherwise you cannot derive anything from Von Neumann.